# Как передать введенные данные из QLineEditв таблицу QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

Как передать введенные данные из `QLineEdit` в таблицу `QTableView`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QTableView, QGridLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.table = QTableView(self)
    self.model = QStandardItemModel()
    self.table.setModel(self.model)
    self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Имя", "Палата"])

    self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить", self)
    self.years = QLabel('Возраст')

    self.years_line = QLineEdit()
    self.diagnose_line = QLineEdit()
    self.diagnose = QLabel('Диагноз')
    self.otd_line = QLineEdit()
    self.otd = QLabel('Отделение')
    self.gender_line = QLineEdit()
    self.gender = QLabel('Пол')
    self.name_line = QLineEdit()
    self.name = QLabel('Имя')
    self.init()

def init(self):
    grid = QGridLayout()
    self.setLayout(grid)

    self.name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.name_line.setPlaceholderText('Введите имя...')
    grid.addWidget(self.name, 1, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.name_line, 2, 1)

    self.gender.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.gender_line.setPlaceholderText('Введите пол...')
    grid.addWidget(self.gender, 3, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.gender_line, 4, 1)

    self.years.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.years_line.setPlaceholderText('Введите возраст...')
    grid.addWidget(self.years, 5, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.years_line, 6, 1)

    self.otd.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.otd_line.setPlaceholderText('Введите отделение...')
    grid.addWidget(self.otd, 7, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.otd_line, 8, 1)

    self.diagnose.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.diagnose_line.setPlaceholderText('Введите диагноз...')
    grid.addWidget(self.diagnose, 9, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.diagnose_line, 10, 1)

    self.table.move(10, 100)
    self.table.resize(517, 400)
    grid.addWidget(self.table, 12, 1, 5, 1)

    grid.addWidget(self.btn, 11, 1, 1, -10)
    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)

    self.resize(700, 500)
    self.setWindowTitle('?')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('key.png'))
    self.show()

def add(self):
    model = QStandardItemModel(4, 4)
    for row in range(4):
        for column in range(4):
            item = QStandardItem("row %d, column %d" % (row, column))
            model.setItem(row, column, item)
    self.name_line.clear()
    self.diagnose_line.clear()
    self.otd_line.clear()
    self.years_line.clear()
    self.gender_line.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подправил ваш метод `add`, а заодно и немного сократил ваш код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QTableView, QGridLayout, QListWidget, QLabel, QListView, QTabWidget, QFrame, \
    QHeaderView, QFormLayout                                                        # +++
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableView(self)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Имя", "Пол", "Возраст", "Отделение", "Диагноз"])

        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)                                    # +
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.Stretch)  # +

        self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)

        self.years = QLabel('Возраст', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.years.setMaximumWidth(60)
        self.years_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите возраст...')
        self.diagnose_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите диагноз...')
        self.diagnose = QLabel('Диагноз', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.otd_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите отделение...')
        self.otd = QLabel('Отделение', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.gender_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите пол...')
        self.gender = QLabel('Пол', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.name_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите имя...')
        self.name = QLabel('Имя', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.name, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.name_line, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.gender, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.gender_line, 2, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.years, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.years_line, 3, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.otd, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.otd_line, 4, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.diagnose, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.diagnose_line, 5, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn, 6, 1, 1, 3) #, 1, -10)
        grid.addWidget(self.table, 7, 0, 5, 4)

    def add(self):
        rows = self.model.rowCount()
        columns = self.model.columnCount()
        for column in range(columns):
            if column == 0:
                self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.name_line.text()))
            if column == 1:
                self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.gender_line.text()))
            if column == 2:
                self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.years_line.text()))
            if column == 3:
                self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.otd_line.text()))
            if column == 4:
                self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.diagnose_line.text()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(700, 500)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Как передать введенные данные из LineEdit в таблицу?')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('key.png'))
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы - мой спаситель

Comment: как я понял, правильный ответ - это зеленая галочка. Мог бы я вас снова попросить о помощи?

Comment: @novol вы все правильно поняли. Просить никого не надо, публикуйте вопрос, который вы не можете решить. Пишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается и конечно прикладываете свои пример над которым вы работаете.